# When $x\otimes y=0$, what can we say about $x$ and $y$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, tensor-products

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with unit $1$ and $M$, $N$ be $A$-modules. Consider tensor product of $M\otimes N$. I wonder when $x\otimes y=0$, what can we say about $x$ and $y$?

I know that if $x=0$ or $y=0$, we get $x\otimes y=0$, or when $x=at$ for some $a\in A,t \in M$ and $ay=0$ then $x\otimes y=0$, too.

Comment: For every bilinear map $B: M\times N\to P $, we will have  $B (x,y)=0$.

Comment: The setting is too general. To see what may happen, so that $x,y$ may be arbitrary, let us take a situation like $A=\Bbb Z$, $M=\Bbb Z/3$, and $N=\Bbb Z/5$. Then we have for instance in $M\otimes N=(\Bbb Z/3)\otimes (\Bbb Z/5)$ the relation $$1\otimes 1=1\otimes 6=1\otimes(6\cdot1)=(1\cdot 6)\otimes 1=0\otimes 1=0\ .$$In a similar manner, we can show that we have $x\otimes y=0$ for all $x,y$ in the corresponding modules... We cannot say anything... (Except for $x,y$ being arbitrary.)